# What is the best configuration of Dell laptop and which data card is compatible with 10.04?

Tags: dell

I am planning to purchase a laptop. I have a couple of questions:

1. What is the best configuration of Dell laptop?
2. Which modem or data card will be useful, if I am going to install Ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 1):

Running 10.04 will be a security risk as of April 2013 as it will no longer be updated.

In answer to your question certified hardware lists can be found [**here**](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/make/Dell/?category=Laptop) for the entire Dell laptop

Or you can search [**here**](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/) by the individual components.

I would recommend that you install 12.04(supported until April 2017).

Comment: 10.04 is an LTS right? so it still have 2 years. LTS have 4/5 years cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead with your 10.04 install. It is a great OS. Also the DE, Gnome 2 is pretty great. It will give you least troubles. Plus if you are in India, most of the Datacards works out of Box. But getting something with good bandwidth and speed will be good for you as you need to update in start and it will be some 300mb plus.

Btw as recommended by other user,never upgrade to 11.10, if u can use 12.04 as it is an LTS. My recommendation is that always use LTS. They are supported for a long period of time (min 4/5)years and you don't need to upgrade to subsequent releases and have a stable and productive system.